# HTTP Header Manager in test fragment is not working

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I was testing some REST endpoint with JMeter. Each request requires `access_token` for calling any of this API. My access tokens are in a CSV file, for removing duplication I've used a test fragment `Request Header` in this test fragment I've read the CSV file and initialized `HTTP Header Manager` using the access token. Later imported the `Request Header` test fragment in each request with `Module Controller`. But for those request test fragment `HTTP Header Manager` is not inheriting from `Request Header` and shows

```json
{
    "message": "Missing Authorization Header"
}
```

But if I use this `HTTP Header Manager` in each request individually it works fine. Yeah, I can continue with duplication but need to remove those duplications.

Structure of my test plan

[image]

HTTP Header Manager
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is kind of violating [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/), if you have a HTTP Header Manager under a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) - it will be applied only to HTTP Request samplers which reside **under that Test Fragment**.

So if you want the HTTP Header Manager to be applied to **all HTTP Request samplers** in your test plan - just put it under the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) element (the same level as Thread Groups) and it will be applied to all HTTP Request samplers in all Thread Groups